# Is there a general rule for addition or subtration of two numbers with the same base but different exponents?

Tags: arithmetic, exponential-sum

I see the product and quotient rules in a quick online search, but I can't find amything for addition and subtraction.

For example, a special case is:

$$2^6 - 2^5 = 2^5$$
$$2^5 - 2^4 = 2^4$$

$$3^6 - 3^5 = (3-1)3^5$$
$$3^5 - 3^4 = (3-1)3^4$$

Therefore this can be generalized for all subtraction where exponents are 1 degree away as...
$$a^{n+1} - a^n = (a-1)a^n$$

However when the exponents are more than 1 degree away, it appears to not be simplifiable...
$$2^5 - 2^3 = 24$$

If it is not simplifiable, are there at least any tricks to solve it short of busting out a calculator?

Otherwise, is there some way to extend the simple case above to an even more generalizable solution?

[Exponent Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goaaS.png)

Comment: You can write $a^n-a^m=a^m(a^{n-m} - 1)$, but idk if you consider that simpler.

Comment: As suggested by the comment of @peek-a-boo, one way of attacking the problem is to re-interpret (for example) an expression like $~3^6 - 3^5~$ as the **polynomial,** $~f(x) = x^6 - x^5,~$ where you are only specifically interested in the value of $~f(x)~$ at (for example) $~x=3.~$  Then, you can apply the standard polynomial factoring rules, such as $~f(x) = x^5(x - 1),~$ and then **convert** this factorization into the equivalent expression when $~x=3.$

Comment: Thank you! That's very helpful!